# Is it possible to detect just the new line input with scanf?

Tags: c

I want to reproduce a terminal behavior, and if possible using `scanf`:

When the user just inputs a new line, the terminal keeps printing the directory, until a real command is inserted.
The normal behavior of the function `scanf` when a new line is inserted, is to keep jumping empty lines waiting for the user to really insert a valid character.

Observation: this terminal simulation is running while i execute ./main.out , this means i'm not talking about my OS terminal, i'm talking about a simulated terminal in C to my program.

what usually happens with `scanf` when you insert empty lines:

```
realPC:~/realDirectory$ ./main.out //starting our simulated terminal
pc:~/Desktop$ '\n'
'\n'
'\n'
"COMMAND\n"         //PROCESS THE COMMAND!
pc:~/Desktop$       //waiting...
```

what i want:

```
realPC:~/realDirectory$ ./main.out //starting our simulated terminal
pc:~/Desktop$ '\n'
pc:~/Desktop$ '\n'
pc:~/Desktop$ '\n'
pc:~/Desktop$ "COMMAND\n" //Process the command here
pc:~/Desktop$             //waiting...
```

This directory is just an example, i want to print any message (for example, keep printing arrows `">>>"` after empty inputs), the problem is that `scanf` seems to don't even consider `'\n'` a input, so i can't print anything

I know that `fgets(userInput, 1024, stdin)` works instead of scanf, but i'd like to know if it is possible using the scanf function (i'm not used to fgets, i'm also accepting other solutions sugestions too, if possible)

Here's the code (the `scanf` isn't working on both uses as i'm pretending to):

```
int main()
{
    char userInput[1024];
    char pwd[] = "pc:~/marcospb19"; // Directory that keeps being printed

    while (1)
    {
        printf("%s$ " , pwd); // Print the directory just like terminals do

        scanf(" %s" , userInput); // I wanted this to enter the while and keep printing directory
        while (userInput[0] == '\n') // Keeps the input inside the loop, if is a new line
        {
            puts("We're inside this loop! that's good, now keep printing directory...");
            printf("%s$ " , pwd); // Directory printed, next: take input again
            scanf(" %s" , userInput); // This should be able to receive '\n'.
            // This loop should continue if user types '\n'
        }

        // Now, you can process the input, it isn't empty!
        printf("Process the input: %s\n", userInput);
    }
}
```

Obviously, when i say the user types `'\n'`, he is just hitting the enter key (not really typing it).

Comment: I suspect a `fgets` and some input massaging will serve you better than `scanf` (and that's usually the case regardless).

Comment: You will likely find `fgets` + `sscanf` easier to use than `scanf` alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scanf` rapidly gets complicated](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) because it mixes up reading input with processing input. When all you want to do is read a line and do something with it [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) is more appropriate. Read the line, then process it however you like. You can even use `sscanf` to stay in the scanf family.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char userInput[1024];
    char pwd[] = "pc:~/marcospb19"; // Directory that keeps being printed

    printf("%s$ " , pwd);
    while (fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if( strcmp(userInput, "\n") == 0 ) {
            puts("Empty input.");
        } 
        else {
            puts("Some input");
        }

        printf("%s$ " , pwd);
    }

    puts("");
}
```

This also lets you do more complex processing, like look for blank lines.

```
    if( strspn(userInput, " \t\r\n") == strlen(userInput) ) {
        puts("Blank input.");
    }
```

Note that `fgets` will leave the newline on the end, so you may have to strip the newline off `userInput` before working on it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to detect just the new line input with scanf?

Yes

```
  char eol[2];
  if (scanf("%1[^n]", eol) == 1) {
    puts("Input with just new line");
  else {
    // read the line via other means
  }
```

Problems with `scanf()` and trying to read  a *line* of user input include:

- Difficultly coding in the width limit.
- Need to consume `"\n"` after the prior part of the line.
- Difficultly in a `"\n"` only input.

---

> i'm not used to [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

Better to learn to use the best tool in the standard library shed for reading *lines*, than code some alternative.